# Laravel package development - Configure priority of middleware component in package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm currently developing an internal Laravel package which is used in more than five applications. I register two middleware component in a service provider in the package:

```
public function boot()
{
    /** @var Router $router */
    $router = $this->app['router'];
    $router->pushMiddlewareToGroup('web', ComponentOne::class);
    $router->pushMiddlewareToGroup('web', ComponentTwo::class);
    $router->pushMiddlewareToGroup('api', ComponentOne::class);
    $router->pushMiddlewareToGroup('api', ComponentTwo::class);
}
```

Is there a possibility to configure priority within the package itself? Component one must be executed before component two. The only thing that I found up till now is configure the Kernel class for each application that uses this package:

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
     ComponentOne::class,
     ComponentTwo::class,
];
```